# Why `irb` runs `/snap/bin/irb` eventhoug `which ruby` says `/usr/bin/irb`

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, apt, snap

I am trying to make Ruby works on POP OS. I installed via apt.
`which ruby` returns `/usr/bin/irb` but when I runs `irb` it says `bash: /snap/bin/irb: No such file or directory`

Why does `irb` has default in `/snap/bin/irb`? I read that `bash` looks into `PATH` to find `irb`, and `/usr/bin` is before `/snap/bin`. I have installed via snap before but have removed it. I was trying to install it in different ways to see why I can't install gems due to no permission. I have chmod +rwx the folder.

When i install ruby via snap, then irb runs. But when i run `gem install rspec`, it says `bash: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory`. Now to install gem it looks into `/usr/bin` instead of `/snap/bin`, why?